How to get all the data from cubepilot orange connected to Ubuntu using data cable when operating a servomotor connected to the cube orange?
Components I use

Cube orange
Ubuntu with Mission Planner(used mono package)
Flysky Transmitter
Flysky 2.4Ghz 10 channel Receiver
Servomotor to operate flaps

My Process

I have paired the receiver and transmitter, the receiver is connected to the cube orange
I have connected the servomotor to the cube orange, once I move the joystick in the transmitter the servomotor should rotate(I haven't done this yet)
Now that my servo is rotating when giving an input, I have the cube orange connected to a ubuntu system, whenever the servo rotates I need that data into that Ubuntu computer, how to do this?

What I have tried till now

Asked ChatGPT it says to calibrate the cube orange first, I don't have any drone equipments to calibrate only a cube orange and a servo motor.
Is there a way to bypass calibration and operate only the servomotor with mission planner?
If not is there is a way to operate cube orange using python packages like dronekit and pymavlink such that it controls the servomotor through cube orange and echoes the data back?

